# Unity ADS Object reference not set to an instance of an object error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

1. As seen in the photo, when the game is opened for the first time, the advertisement comes, but I don't want it to come.
2. When I click "skull gameobject" in the photo, I want the ad to appear, but I give an error, I could not fix the error and I also want time to stop, but time does not stop.
   In the 3rd photo, there are AdsScript codes.

#1

[image]

#2

[image]

#3

[image]

```
public void GameoverPanel()
{
    if (Time.timeScale == 1f)
    {
        gameoverPanel.SetActive(true);
        AdsScript.instance.RequestInterstitial();
    }
    Time.timeScale = 0f;

}



public InterstitialAd interstitial;

void Start()
{
    MobileAds.Initialize(App_ID => { });
    //MobileAds.Initialize(App_ID);

    RequestInterstitial();
}

public void RequestInterstitial()
{
        // Initialize an InterstitialAd.
        this.interstitial = new InterstitialAd(Interstitial_AD_ID);

        AdRequest reguest = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        this.interstitial.LoadAd(reguest);

        GameOver();
}

public void GameOver()
{
        if (this.interstitial.IsLoaded())
        {
            this.interstitial.Show();
        }
}
```

Comment: You don't show how and where you set `AdsScript.instance` .. obviously seems to be a Singleton Pattern so I'm pretty sure the issue is either A) That component is not attached to anything in your scene **at all** .. or B) you are trying to access it before the singleton initialized itself ... Besides that please note that `unityscript` is or better was a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in previous Unity versions and is long deprecated by now! Your code is clearly `c#` ...

Comment: Also note that you get the warning about trying to create a `MonoBehaviour` using `new` .. maybe you should not ignore it ;) ... Wherever you do: **THIS IS NOT ALLOWED FOR MONOBEHAVIOUR!** .. people do it anyway all the time .... There are only 3 valid ways of creating a new instance of a `MonoBehaviour`: 1) Use `new GameObject("some name", typeof(YourScript));` 2) use `someGameObject.AddComponent<YourScript>();` or 3) use `Instantiate` and pass in a prefab that already has that component attached ...

Comment: 2) use someGameObject.AddComponent<YourScript>();
2.I used it worked thanks sir.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove ad at the start do not call `GameOver` method in `RequestInterstitial` method instead call it in `GameoverPanel` method. if you wish to load the ad again to show next time the game overs you may want to load it again for example it should be like this:

```
public void GameoverPanel()
{
    if (Time.timeScale == 1f)
    {
        gameoverPanel.SetActive(true);
        GameOver();
        RequestInterstitial();
    }
    Time.timeScale = 0f;

}
```

Secondly set Adscript to the public then drag and drop it in the inspector(if ads and GameOverPanel method script are in a different class).

Comment: thanks for your help but unfortunately it didn't work